# POSTGRES - Insert only if certain column is filled out

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

**Have:**

```
ID start_date  end_date     account 
1   2016-06-30  null         123
1   2017-04-19  null         111
1   2017-04-26  2017-07-30   789
```

**Would like to accomplish:**

Is there a way to create a constraint/index/other mechanism that will check that:

1. If ID and Account exist and end date is null -> do nothing
2. If ID and Account exist and end date is not null -> insert the row

**So:**

```
insert into table (ID, start_date, account) values (1,2016-08-01,123)
```

-> NOTHING HAPPENS

```
insert into table (ID, start_date, account) values (1,2017-04-26, 789)
```

-> INSERT ROW

I was thinking maybe a CHECK constraint with stored function that will check the above or something of that sort? Or index:

```
create unique index unique_account on table (ID, account) where end_date is null
```

Comment: You can achieve that by wrapping the insert into stored procedure. And then denying write access to the table. So all writes will have to come through the procedure where you apply all the necessary checks. Oh, but you were already thinking about that.

Comment: I got ther feeling that you actually want a constraint that enforces non-overlapping date-ranges (per {id,account}) In that case, using `+infinity` for an *open* interval would be more practical than NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is The BEST PRACTICE**

**WARNING:** Use Trigger in highly transaction database will cause performance issue.

**Solution: I assume you use PostgreSQL 9.5 or Above**

Until this step you almost done

```
create unique index unique_account on table (ID, account) where end_date is null
```

All you have to do is using `UPSERT` query in PostgreSQL 9.5 or Above

**ANS CASE 1:**

```
Insert into insert_only (ID, start_date, account) values (1,'2016-08-01',123) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

*we need unique index for `"CONFLICT"`. This Query Mean if you insert same `id + acoount + date is null` Then `"ON CONFLICT"` will execute and `DO NOTHING`.

**ANS CASE 2:**

```
Insert into insert_only (ID, start_date, end_date,account) values (1,'2016-08-01','2016-08-01',789) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

*Using the same query we input `end_date` value on account `789` the insert will be successful.

**OUTPUT:**

```
BEFORE: 

stackoverflow=# select * from insert_only;
 id | start_date |  end_date  | account 
----+------------+------------+---------
  1 | 2016-08-01 |            |     123
  1 | 2017-08-01 |            |     111
  1 | 2017-04-26 | 2017-07-30 |     789
  1 | 2016-08-01 | 2016-08-01 |     789
(4 rows)

stackoverflow=# Insert into insert_only (ID, start_date, account) values (1,'2016-08-01',123) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
INSERT 0 0

stackoverflow=# Insert into insert_only (ID, start_date, end_date,account) values (1,'2016-08-01','2016-08-01',789) ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
INSERT 0 1

AFTER:

stackoverflow=# select * from insert_only;
 id | start_date |  end_date  | account 
----+------------+------------+---------
  1 | 2016-08-01 |            |     123
  1 | 2017-08-01 |            |     111
  1 | 2017-04-26 | 2017-07-30 |     789
  1 | 2016-08-01 | 2016-08-01 |     789
  1 | 2016-08-01 | 2016-08-01 |     789
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Hope this solution help you. and never use trigger in insert for validating that will cause trouble in the future when your data is growing like 1 million.